# How to simplify this JQuery Code

Tags: jquery, styles, simplify, convention

this code works totally fine for me, to highlight the links of the navbar when I'm in a certain sector of my page.

But I'm pretty sure, there is a simpler / shortend up code, that does the same.
The problem is, i just copied and pasted this code together, because I have no idea how JQuery works.

Can anyone give me a hint how to simplify this code?

> ```
>   <!-- START-AREA -->
>   $(function() {                     
>       $('beginstart').waypoint(function() {
>           $('#sec-start').addClass('active');
>           $('#sec-info').removeClass('active');
>           $('#sec-kontakt').removeClass('active');
>           $('#sec-referenzen').removeClass('active');
>           $('#sec-angebot').removeClass('active');
>           $('#sec-impressum').removeClass('active');
>       })});
> ```

```
  $('endstart').waypoint(function() {
      $('#sec-start').addClass('active');
      $('#sec-info').removeClass('active');
      $('#sec-kontakt').removeClass('active');
      $('#sec-referenzen').removeClass('active');
      $('#sec-angebot').removeClass('active');
      $('#sec-impressum').removeClass('active');
  }, {
      offset: 'bottom-in-view'
  });
```

This is for only one section, but I have six of them, so it would be really cool to have that shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Combine the selector by comma separating](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), also you can use the same function in both case.

```js
<!-- START-AREA -->
$(function() {
  // define it as a function
  var fun = function() {
    $('#sec-start').addClass('active');
    $('#sec-info,#sec-kontakt,#sec-referenzen,#sec-angebot,#sec-impressum').removeClass('active');
  };
  // use the function reference  in both
  $('beginstart').waypoint(fun);
  $('endstart').waypoint(fun, {
    offset: 'bottom-in-view'
  });
});
```

Comment: alternatively, depending on HTML setup and expected results, he could just say `$('.active').removeClass(); $('.selector').addClass();`

Answer (score 1):

You can group multiple selectors together with commas

```
$(function() {                     
      $('beginstart').waypoint(function() {
          $('#sec-start').addClass('active');
          $('#sec-info, #sec-kontakt, #sec-referenzen, 
             #sec-angebot, #sec-impressum').removeClass('active');
      })});
```